# Column values are repeating in output

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have table named BATTERY containing 3 columns, `BATTERY_PN, MSDS_FILE_NAME` and `UNDOT_FILE_NAME`. The data in the table is as below.

```
BATTERY_PN         MSDS_FILE_NAME                           UNDOT_FILE_NAME
135259-0000        MSDS_ API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF        UNDOT_ API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF
135259-0000        MSDS_ API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF        China Sea Cert API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF
```

I want to write a select statement that will not repeat any column name value. If I have 3 different `MSDS_FILE_NAME` values it should show 3 rows and last row will have `NULL` in `UNDOT_FILE_NAME`.

**Expected Output:**

```
BATTERY_PN         MSDS_FILE_NAME                           UNDOT_FILE_NAME
135259-0000        MSDS_ API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF        UNDOT_ API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF
135259-0000                                                 China Sea Cert API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF
```

Comment: Your expected outcome and explanation do not match.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, if I understand correctly, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select BATTERY_PN,
       (case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by battery_pn, MSDS_FILE_NAME order by UNDOT_FILE_NAME)
             then MSDS_FILE_NAME
        end) as MSDS_FILE_NAME,
       UNDOT_FILE_NAME
from battery;
```

Comment: This doesn't work when `MSDS_FILE_NAME` have 3 different values and `UNDOT_FILE_NAME` have 2 values.

Answer (score -1):

```
create table battery(BATTERY_PN varchar2(100),MSDS_FILE_NAME varchar2(100),UNDOT_FILE_NAME varchar2(100));
insert into battery values('135259-0000', 'MSDS_ API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF','UNDOT_ API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF');
insert into battery values('135259-0000', 'MSDS_ API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF',' China Sea Cert API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF');
insert into battery values('135259-0000', 'MSDS_ API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF','UNDOT_ API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF');
insert into battery values('135259-0000', 'MSDS_ API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF',' China Sea Cert API-700-008685-005 40GP.PDF');


SELECT battery_pn,(case when 1=rownum
    then
    msds_file_name END)  as MSDS_FILE_NAME ,undot_file_name 
FROM battery;
```